# powershell needed for a springboot project dependency

Tags: linux, spring-boot, docker, rhel

Hi So im working a project where a springboot project uses a maven dependency [jpowershell](https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell)

Now my problem is i have dockerized the project with a rhel 7 base image and also installing powershell and trying to run my docker image but get the error and the docker container exits

***PowerShell not available
com.profesorfalken.jpowershell.PowerShellNotAvailableException: Cannot execute PowerShell.exe. Please make sure that it is installed in your system***

This is my docker file ,am following the correct procedure or am i making some mistake .Any help will be much appreciated

```
FROM something.abc.com/test-base/rhel:7

ENV http_proxy http://http.proxy.xyz.com:8000
ENV https_proxy http://http.proxy.xyz.com:8000
ENV no_proxy localhost,127.0.0.1,.xyz.com
ENV PATH="/usr/java/jdk-15.0.1/bin:$PATH"

# Install common packages

RUN yum install -y bzip2
RUN yum install -y wget
RUN wget https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.3.7/powershell-7.3.7-1.rh.x86_64.rpm
RUN yum install -y powershell-7.3.7-1.rh.x86_64.rpm
RUN pwsh --version


# Download and Install OpenJDK 15

RUN cd /tmp && wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk15.0.1/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/9/GPL/openjdk-15.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvzf openjdk-15.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz && \
    mkdir -p /usr/java && mv /tmp/jdk-15.0.1 /usr/java


VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/xyz-*.jar /app/xyz/sample.jar

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app/xyz/sample.jar"]
```

This is the error when i run the docker container
[image]

Powershell paths
[image]

[image]

Comment: What directory contains PowerShell.exe and what directories are in PATH?

Comment: Why are you installing powershell?

Comment: @LinFelix one of the maven dependencies in my springboot project need PowerShell to execute  jpowershell-->https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell

Comment: `ENV PATH="/usr/java/jdk-15.0.1/bin:$PATH"` adds a directory to PATH. Either the directory with PowerShell.exe is not in PATH or its name is incorrect.

Comment: @stark  i have edited my post ,so you thin this will be the home path for powershell ?$PSHOME is /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/

Comment: Copy your docker file. Try adding another ENV PATH line with that directory. If it doesn't work you can restore the original file.

Comment: Will try that and update @stark

Comment: which version of jpowershell are you using?

Comment: @tobifasc version 3.1.1

Comment: alright 3.1.1 should support linux... Considering your `pwsh --version` command works what i'd try is [change the executable](https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell/tree/master#setting-the-powershell-executable-path) to `pwsh`.

Comment: @tobifasc yes pwsh command works i have edited the post  and added the image above ,will check the link you provided

Comment: @stark adding env path didn't resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined [in the powershell docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.3#renamed-powershellexe-to-pwshexe) after Powershell 5.1:

> The binary name for PowerShell has been changed from **powershell(.exe)** to **pwsh(.exe)**

[jPowershell](https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell) is looking for a binary called `powershell` which will not work in your environment.

One possible solution is changing the executable name jPowershell is looking for (as described [here](https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell#setting-the-powershell-executable-path)):

```
//Creates PowerShell session
try (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.openSession("pwsh")) {
   ...
}
```